# Not retrieving image from FirebaseStorage in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm trying to retrieve an image from Firebase Storage, but the Url it gives to me don't work...Picasso can't load it.

This is the code i'm working with:

```
var image: Task<Uri>? = null

        image = mImageStorage.child("images/profile/" + auth.currentUser.uid).downloadUrl
                .addOnSuccessListener {
            if(image.toString()!=""){
                Picasso.get().load(image.toString()).into(userPic)
                Log.println(Log.INFO,"url ",image.toString())
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Need to choose an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
                .addOnFailureListener{
                    Log.println(Log.INFO, "error ", it.toString())
                }
```

This is the url that Logcat gives to me: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@262ccd5

[image: This is a pic from Firebase]

I've searched how to retrieve the Token, but i didn't found nothing...
Can I get some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `image.toString()` is the download URL. In the `onSuccess` callback , I think it should be something like `it.toString()`. So:

```
Picasso.get().load(it.toString()).into(userPic)
```

Comment: Thanks, it workd. It's normal that it takes so long to load the image?